# How to use a R-Tree in Cassandra as indexing

Tags: indexing, cassandra, b-tree, r-tree

As [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759807/what-is-the-index-structure-of-cassandra) said: "In version 3.4 they introduced SASI indexes (SSTable Attached Secondary Indexes). Basically a portion of the index is associated to each SStable and hence distributed with it. This means you can actually use references to access data rather than pay for another read path. In terms of implementation, they are b-trees."

So I want to replace R-Tree instead of B-Tree for indexing is Cassandra. Cassandra is in java, I see all files about B-Tree there in a folder but there is no documentation about parameters and functions there. I have R-Tree source code in java but I don't know how replace it in Cassandra as it indexing method.

p.s. the language doesn't matter for me and can be anyone. no limits.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad and general.

My advice is that you first familiarise yourself with the implementation and inner-workings of secondary indexes in Cassandra before embarking on an ambitious goal of rewriting the code. Cheers!

Comment: It is indexing and more inner, not secondary index.